# How do I link to a shared library?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I installed a new lib from source and I am trying to link to it. The linker complains that it cannot find the symbols that should be in the lib.

Here are the errors I get:

```
$ make all
gcc -std=c99 -g -Wall -O3 `pkg-config --cflags --libs libmodbus` -c client.c -o client.o
gcc -std=c99 -g -Wall -O3 `pkg-config --cflags --libs libmodbus` client.o -o client
client.o: In function `main':
/home/gauthier/code/modbus/client.c:29: undefined reference to `modbus_new_tcp'
/home/gauthier/code/modbus/client.c:30: undefined reference to `modbus_connect'
/home/gauthier/code/modbus/client.c:33: undefined reference to `modbus_read_registers'
/home/gauthier/code/modbus/client.c:35: undefined reference to `modbus_close'
/home/gauthier/code/modbus/client.c:36: undefined reference to `modbus_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [client] Error 1
```

`pkg-config` says this:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs libmodbus
-I/usr/local/include/modbus  -L/usr/local/lib -lmodbus
```

and the files in `/usr/local/lib` are these:

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/ | grep mod
libmodbus.la
libmodbus.so
libmodbus.so.5
libmodbus.so.5.0.5
```

Also, the so file contains the undefined references:

```
$ grep modbus_connect /usr/local/lib/*
Binary file /usr/local/lib/libmodbus.so matches
Binary file /usr/local/lib/libmodbus.so.5 matches
Binary file /usr/local/lib/libmodbus.so.5.0.5 matches
```

I tried adding `/usr/local/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, to no av. Not that I though it would help since I have `-L` in my compiler command anyway.

I also tried to manually write the `-I`, `-L`, and `-l` (not using `pkg-config`), that didn't help.

How do I make the linker understand that the references to the `modbus_*` functions are right there?

Comment: gcc -v xxx to see verbose

Comment: put the -lmodbus to the end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me guess.

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the
>   linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order
>   they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after
>   file foo.o but before bar.o. If **bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’,
>   those functions may not be loaded**.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

So try put `pkg-config --cflags --libs libmodbus` at the end

Comment: The worst is that I actually already read this, but misinterpreted it. I though that the linker read left to right, and needed to have read the lib before reading the object file that would make use of it. It is the opposite, the linker seems to need to know what symbols are missing, before taking them in from the lib.